# Positioning Vertices in a Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I made a graph that has a given number at each vertex:

[image: Lattice Graph for D_16]

I want to place vertex 1 above vertex 2 if value of vertex 1 is larger than of vertex 2. And also, vertices with same value should be located on the same horizontal line.

Above graph satisfies the condition. (I think because of luck.)

But, another graph constructed by the same function does not satisfy it:

[image: Lattice Graph for D_10]

Here 5 is not above 2.

How can I implement this condition?

(The height of the gap between 2 and 5 does not need to be exactly 3 times the height gap between 1 and 2.)

==== Editted ====

Here is the code for function makes the graph. (I simplified it.)

```
LatticeGraph[group_] :=
    Module[{subgroup = (*omitted*), nodes, edges, list},
        nodes = Table[Property[Labeled[i, Placed[subgroup[[i]], Center]],(*VertexStyle Omitted*)], {i, 1, Length[subgroup]}];
        list = {(*Omitted and it's used for generate edges*)}
        edges = {(*Omitted and it was just the list of v1->v2*)};

        Graph[nodes, edges, VertexSize -> Large,EdgeShapeFunction -> GraphElementData["Line"], ImagePadding -> 20]]
```

Comment: How did you make the first one? And the second one? Please provide some code.

Comment: Ok. I will edit my post.

Comment: Why omitting parts? You should provide the `subgroup`, `list` etc who produced the second `Graph` at least.

Comment: I think it is not related to this question. you can consider  subgroup as the list of values, ex) {10,5,2,2,2,2,2,1} for the second image. and the list of edges are not needed since my condition is just for vertices, not for edges.

Comment: Your two examples show some regularities that could be exploited to get a simple function, but you need to be more specific about them. For example, no edges between "twin" nodes, no "Mixed Layers" links, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vertices = Range[7];
labels = {10, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1};
(* Note: if labels is not already sorted in descending order, 
   use labels = Sort[labels, Greater] -- thanks: @TeakeNutma  *)
labels2 = Thread[vertices -> 
         (Placed[#, Center] & /@ (Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@labels))];
vp = Last /@ Tally[labels]; (*thanks: Oska *)
edges = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, 
                            {1, 6}, {2, 7}, {3, 7}, {4, 7}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}};

Rotate[
  Graph[vertices, edges,
        VertexLabels -> labels2,
        VertexSize -> Large,
        GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> vp}], -90 Degree]
```

[image]

**Update:**  To deal with overlapping edges,

Modify vertex coordinates for selected edges:

```
vertices2 = Range[8];
newedges = UndirectedEdge @@@ {{1, 8}, {8, 7}};
edges2 = Join[edges, newedges] /. {7 -> 8, 8 -> 7};
labels2 = {10, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1};
labels2b =  Thread[vertices2 -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ 
                                (Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ labels2))];
vp2 = Last /@ Tally[labels2]; 

gA = Graph[vertices2, edges2, VertexLabels -> labels2b, 
          VertexSize -> Large, 
          GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> vp2}];
vc = # /.  MapIndexed[#1 -> #1 + {0, (-1)^(First@#2) .15} &, 
                      Cases[#, {_, 0.}][[2 ;; -2]]] &@GraphEmbedding[gA];
Rotate[SetProperty[gA, VertexCoordinates -> vc], -90 Degree]
```

[image]

Or, keep the `VertexCoordinates` and use an `EdgeShapeFunction` to curve selected edges:

```
esF = Function[{pts}, 
        If[pts[[1, 2]] == pts[[2, 2]] && pts[[2, 1]] - pts[[1, 1]] > 1, 
           BezierCurve[{pts[[1]], {(pts[[1, 1]] + pts[[2, 1]])/2, 
                      pts[[2, 2]] + (-1)^(1 + Round[pts[[1, 1]]]) (#)}, pts[[2]]}], 
           Line[{pts[[1]], pts[[2]]}]]] &;
gB = Graph[vertices2, edges2, VertexLabels -> labels2b, 
          VertexSize -> Large, 
          GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> vp2},
          EdgeShapeFunction -> esF[.3]];
Rotate[gB, -90 Degree]
```

[image]

Comment: @Oska, thank you.. I updated with your suggestion using `Tally` to get vertex partition. Although `GraphLayout` was introduced in version 8, it was updated substantially in version 9. `MapAt` also went through some undocumented/silent updates in version 9.

Comment: This only works if the labels are in reverse canonical order; e.g. `labels = {5, 10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1}` fails. Some sorting should fix this though.

Comment: @TeakeNutma Yes, I added the code for sorting before using this method.

Comment: @TeakeNutma, thank you. Will update with your suggestion.

Comment: You would be faster to directly do `labels=Sort[labels,Greater]`. I guess it wouldn't cost too much computing time.

Comment: Sorting the labels alone is not sufficient though; for generic input `{labels, vertices, edges}` you'll need to replace the vertex numbers in `vertices` and `edges` to match the sorted `labels`. But @Analysis has indicated that he sorts everything before producing the graph, so it actually won't be necessary for the OP's purposes.

Comment: How can I avoid edge overlapping? It occurs when {10,5,2,2,2,2,2,1}, i.e. add one vertex with the label of 2 which is connected to 1 and 10 from your graph.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a kind of [Hasse diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5355/5485). 
Unfortunately, there is no [`GraphLayout`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphLayout.html) that does exactly what you want out of the box. (Although [kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kguler) has shown in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56860/5485) you can coax `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` into the desired behaviour).

However, it still can also be done with specifying the option [`VertexCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html) of [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html). This requires us to compute appropriate coordinates of all vertices based on their label. It's a bit of work, but perfectly doable nonetheless.

Since you haven't given the necessary details of your graph generating function, I'll be using your second example with an additional "2" vertex:

```
vertices = Thread @ Labeled[Range[8], {10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2}];
edges    = UndirectedEdge @@@ {
    {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 8},
    {2, 7}, {3, 7}, {4, 7}, {5, 7}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}
}
```

We need to determine the vertex coordinates from their labels.
For this you can write a custom function (which is what I did in [the first draft of this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/56838/1)), but you can also use the power of the `Combinatorica` package:

```
Block[{$ContextPath},
  << Combinatorica`;
]

coordinates = Sequence @@@ Extract[
  Combinatorica`HasseDiagram @ Combinatorica`MakeGraph[vertices, Last@#1 < Last@#2 &], 
  2
]
```

> ```
> {{0., 4.}, {-1.5, 2.}, {-0.5, 2.}, {0.5, 2.}, {1.5, 2.}, {0., 3.}, {0., 1.}}
> ```

Finally, these coordinates can then be plugged into [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) as an argument for [`VertexCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexCoordinates.html) to get the desired result:

```
Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> coordinates]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is overlap in some of the edges; this can be fixed by simply adding a random perturbation to the x-coordinates of the vertices::

```
perturbedcoordinates = coordinates /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> {x + RandomReal[{-1, 1}/3], y}

Graph[vertices, edges, VertexCoordinates -> perturbedcoordinates]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like the new one :D

Comment: @Öskå Thanks; I also like it much better than my first version (and that's why I changed it :).

Comment: I wonder how you found the ``Combinatorica`HasseDiagram @ Combinatorica`MakeGraph``:D

Comment: @Öskå Well, it's also in the A of the Q&A I linked to, but I initially found it [here](http://mathemaniac.org/wp/2011/10/hasse-diagram-in-mathematica/). The `Combinatorica` docs are a bit sparse unfortunately.

Comment: It is apparently useful :)

Comment: Actually, I have to define 'graph-generating function' in my package. When I use your method, I would load `Combinatorica` but if I do this, many functions in this package have same name of mines. How can I load just 2 functions you used?

Comment: @Analysis If you load the package using `Block[{$ContextPath}, <<Combinatorica\`]` then there's no issue with your custom functions. The shadow warning messages are generated inside the `Block` and have no consequence outside it. You can suppress them with an additional `Quiet`.