# Hasse Diagrams in Mathematica using an arbitrary relation

Tags: graphs-and-networks

As a kludge to draw Hasse diagrams for an assignment, I wrote(based on [this](https://gist.github.com/Eckankar/1315879)):

```
chars = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}; 
nums = Association["a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4, "e" -> 5,"f" -> 6]; 
edges = EdgeList[
   AdjacencyGraph[{{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
           {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, 
           {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}}]];
pOrder[x_, y_] := MemberQ[edges, DirectedEdge[nums[x], nums[y]]]; 
g = MakeGraph[chars, pOrder, VertexLabel -> True]; 
h = HasseDiagram[g]; 
ShowGraph[h, VertexStyle -> PointSize[0.1], VertexLabelColor -> White, 
   VertexLabelPosition -> {0.025, 0}, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}]
```

I have read [Is it possible to generate a Hasse Diagram for a defined relation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-hasse-diagram-for-a-defined-relation) but the only answer provided was deeply insufficient for me, since contacting the authors or buying the book would take a long time or money. So my question is: Is there a *better* way to do this? More precisely: Does mathematica have some object to draw a Hasse Diagram from DirectedEdges or adjacency matrices, preferrably working with labels directly? Optionally, is there a way to relate "a" to 1, "b" to 2 and so on without doing it explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.
I'm trying to answer:

> Does mathematica have some object to draw a Hasse Diagram from DirectedEdges or adjacency matrices

So, let's draw a Hasse Diagram starting from its adjacency matrix:

```
<< Combinatorica`;
am = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};
g = FromAdjacencyMatrix[am, Type -> Directed];
h = HasseDiagram[SetVertexLabels[g, CharacterRange["a", "g"]]];
ShowGraph[h, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This was just was I was looking for! It was just plain odd to use a binary function as a proxy to make things work(and relabeling each vertex "manually").

Comment: I wonder how `HasseDiagram` chooses to arrange the vertices. The placement of vertex `a` in this diagram is puzzling. (Good answer though, of course. I'm just thinking out loud.)

Comment: @KellenMyers Take a look at `C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\AddOns\Packages\Combinatorica`   (or something like that) .[A stripoff of Combinatorica.m](http://pastebin.com/CeP3B4kG) shows that it just uses the vertexes in their raw order and puts them left to right. The function even has an undocumented parameter `fak` that makes the hasse diagram look pyramid-like(coarsely)

Comment: @belisarius I just noted that the range should be ["a","g"]

Comment: @chubakueno Gracias! Cuando veas un error así no dudes en editar la respuesta y corregirlo. Saludos

Comment: Entendido! Saludos también.

Answer (score 3):

The key function used in `` Combinatorica`HasseDiagram `` is the transitive reduction function `TR`.

```
 TR = Compile[{{closure, _Integer, 2}},
   Module[{reduction = closure, n = Length[closure], i, j, k},
     Do[If[reduction[[i, j]] != 0 && reduction[[j, k]] != 0 &&
      reduction[[i, k]] != 0 && (i != j) && (j != k) && (i != k), reduction[[i, k]] = 0],
    {i, n}, {j, n}, {k, n}]; 
    reduction]]
```

You can use the `Combinatorica` function `TR` on your adjacency matrix to get its transitive reduction and use the resulting matrix with `AdjacencyGraph`.

The function `trF` below is an alternative implementation of `TR`.

```
ClearAll[trF];
trF = Module[{r = #, m = Length@#},
  Table[r[[i, k]] = r[[i, k]] (1 - Times @@ Unitize[{r[[i, j]], r[[j, k]], r[[i, k]],
   i - j, j - k, i - k}]), {i, m}, {j, m}, {k, m}]; r] &;
```

Using the example matrix in belisarius's answer:

```
am = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
     1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}};

tram0 = TR[am - IdentityMatrix[Length@am]];
tram = trF[am - IdentityMatrix[Length@am]];
tram == tram0;
(* True *)
```

The `Hasse Diagram` can be obtained using `AdjacencyGraph[tram]`:

```
options = {VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20, 
  DirectedEdges -> False, ImageSize -> 300};

agam = AdjacencyGraph[CharacterRange["a", "g"], am, options];
agtram = AdjacencyGraph[CharacterRange["a", "g"], tram, options, 
   GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> "a", "Orientation" -> Bottom}];

{{"am", "trF[am]"}, {am // MatrixForm, tram2 // MatrixForm}, {agam, agtram}} // Grid
```

[image]

OP's example:

```
am2 = {{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
       {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1}};
tram2 = trF[am2 - IdentityMatrix[Length@am2]];

agam2 = AdjacencyGraph[CharacterRange["a", "f"], am2,  options];
agtram2 = AdjacencyGraph[CharacterRange["a", "f"], tram2, options,
   GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> "a", "Orientation" -> Bottom}];

{{"am2", "trF(am2)"}, {am2 // MatrixForm, tram2 // MatrixForm }, {agam2, agtram2}} // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing an insight to mathematica's inner workings, now I know packages are actually an analyzable .m file :)