# Enforce graph symmetry

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am using

```
dG[nn_] := Graph[With[{aa = Prime@Range@PrimePi@Floor@Sqrt@nn}, 
With[{bb = Sort[Times @@@ Rest@Subsets[aa]]}, #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@
Select[Sort@Subsets[Select[bb, # <= nn &], {2}], 
Divisible[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &]]], DirectedEdges -> False, 
VertexLabels -> "Name", GraphLayout -> "TutteEmbedding"]

dG@70
```

which produces the pleasingly symmetric

[image]

and is great up to `nn=120`. But since `"TutteEmbedding"` works for 3-connected planar graphs only, beyond that, (although `"HighDimensionalEmbedding"` is passable for `nn=121`), I am not getting the desired effect.

Looking [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/graph-vs-graphplot?rq=1), I think it might be possible to try to get Mathematica to recognise a graph type & fit it  to something from `GraphData`, but I haven't managed any success via this route so far.

## Update

If I forgo the `Select[bb,#<= nn &]` restriction, the result is symmetric for `nn=121`, but not very readable:

[image]

whereas if I relax the the link to *all* divisors & settle for a path leading *through* divisors, the Hasse diagram route seems a better option `facGraph[5]`:

[image]

this is extendable of course to the well-known (partial) divisor graph `divGraph[3, 4]`:

[image]

I am still not sure however, to reinforce the `Select[bb,#<= nn &]` restriction, even after looking [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60883/hasse-diagrams-in-mathematica-using-an-arbitrary-relation).

---

```
<< Combinatorica`;

facGraph[nn_] := With[{aa = Subsets[Prime@Range[nn]]}, 
ShowLabeledGraph[HasseDiagram[MakeGraph[Subsets[Range[nn]], 
((Intersection[#2, #1] == #1) && (#1 != #2)) &, VertexLabel -> "Name"]], 
Map[Style[#, 10, Black] &, Times @@@ aa], PlotRange -> All, 
EdgeColor -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], EdgeStyle -> Thin, 
VertexColor -> White, VertexStyle -> {Disk[1/Length@aa]}, 
VertexLabelPosition -> Center, ImageSize -> (20 Length@aa)]]

divGraph[nn_, depth_] := With[{aa = Flatten[SortBy[# & /@ 
SplitBy[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Tuples[Prime@Range[nn], #] & /@
Range@(depth), 1], Sort@#1 == Sort@#2 &], PrimeOmega[Times @@ #] &][[#]], 
Times @@ # &] & /@ Range[depth], 1]}, ShowLabeledGraph[
HasseDiagram[MakeGraph[aa, (Divisible[Times @@ 
#2, Times @@ #1] && Length@#2 == Length@#1 + 1) &, VertexLabel -> "Name"]], 
Map[Style[#, 10, Black] &, Times @@@ aa], PlotRange -> All, 
EdgeColor -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], EdgeStyle -> Thin, 
VertexColor -> White, VertexStyle -> {Disk[1/Length@aa]}, 
VertexLabelPosition -> Center, ImageSize -> (20 Length@aa)]]
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is computing? What does the `Select[bb, # <= nn &]` restriction do exactly?

Comment: @Rahul not a lot - just caps the max element (though I'm not sure I've posted the correct version of the code, now you mention it). Am probably quite happy to settle for the Hasse diagram actually - it is pretty readable, thiough I would have preferred not to use `Combinatorica`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
facGraph[nn_] := 
 With[{aa = 
    Select[Subsets[Prime@Range@PrimePi@Floor@Sqrt@nn], 
     Times @@ # <= nn &]}, 
  ShowLabeledGraph[
   HasseDiagram[
    MakeGraph[aa, (SubsetQ[#2, #1] && (#1 != #2)) &, 
     VertexLabel -> "Name"]], 
   Map[Style[#, 10, Black] &, Times @@@ aa], PlotRange -> All, 
   EdgeColor -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], VertexColor -> White,
    VertexStyle -> {Disk[1/Length@aa]}, VertexLabelPosition -> Center,
    ImageSize -> (20 Length@aa)]]

facGraph[70]
```

[image]

Comment: great! this is what I was after! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[hasseG]
hasseG[nn_, o:OptionsPattern[]]:=  With[{aa = 
   Select[Times @@@ Subsets[Prime @ Range @ PrimePi @ Floor @ Sqrt @ nn], # <= nn &]}, 
 TransitiveReductionGraph[RelationGraph[Divisible, aa], o, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
 PerformanceGoal->"Quality", BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[0]]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
hasseG[70]
```

[image]

```
hasseG[121, EdgeStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]