# Drawing a Hasse diagram

Tags: plotting

I have a binary set and I want to draw a [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) for it.
How can this be done?

This is the set:

```
{11100100,00101101,01111000,11000110,10110001,10000111,11010010,00011011}
```

Comment: There used to be a function for this, called [`HasseDiagram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/HasseDiagram.html), in the now obsolete Combinatorica package.

Comment: closely related/ possible duplicate: [Is it possible to generate a Hasse Diagram for a defined relation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5355/125), [Hasse Diagrams in Mathematica using an arbitrary relation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60883/125).